# How do I create an extra column in an Excel Pivot Table to be able to calculate a percentage when using counts

Tags: excel, pivot-table, calculated-columns

We have an Excel Pivot Table based on a Jet Report table that displays a series of intervals tracking Customer On Time Delivery. The intervals are calculated as the difference between the Shipment Date and the original Requested Delivery Date. An On Time shipment has an interval  of zero. Below is a screenshot of some sample data.

What I would like to do is to add a calculated column to the right of the Total that shows the On Time Percentage calculated as the Zero Interval count / Total count (e.g. 337 / 369 or 1,369 / 1,392), but I don't know how to determine which column contains the Zero Interval count. Is there anyway to do this within an Excel Pivot table? Thanks in advance for any ideas and/or suggestions.

[image: Below is some sample data]